# cakephp highchart fatal error while rendering

Tags: highcharts, cakephp-2.5

Here I am, again. With another question concerning cakephp-2.5 and the plugin 'highcharts'.

I've been looking at the demo's an all the different things I could find were the extendings from the controllers. But... that isn't required because it's a plug, am I right?

So, I have included th plugin to my loadings inside the bootstrap file, and when I'm trying to render my HighChart I'm receiving the following error;

```
Error: Chart: "1" could not be found. Ensure that Chart Name is the same string that is passed to $this->HighCharts->render() in your view.
```

But the demos are working fine! Any idea what I f*cked up? The names are the same, I even renamed them to 'asd' ( both! ) and it still doesn't work. ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin was not yet compatible with CakePHP 2.5. Right now as we speak the developer is working on a new release for 2.5. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an incredibly late response but for the benefit of those still experiencing problems with this, the [CakePHP 2.* Highcharts plugin](https://github.com/destinydriven/cakephp-highcharts-plugin) has been updated and is compatible up to CakePHP version 2.5.7.

Do note however that in order to maintain product name consistency throughout the repo, all previous references to "HighCharts" have been changed to "Highcharts" and "`high_charts`" is now simply "`highcharts`" . So for eg. you now have to call  `$this->Highcharts->render()` where before you would have used `$this->HighCharts->render()`.

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 2.5, you can avoid the error above and render your chart by calling it. 
For example from within index() within your controller, use:

```
$this->bar();
```

In this example, bar() is the name of the function containing your chart.

Comment: I made a mistake with rendering the chart itself. My index was calling a render for another function which was calling the render for the chart. :)